# Cypress tests with Axios

Tags: websocket, axios, cypress

I made some tests within cypress (3.5.0) which use cy.route with an alias to mock the normal page requests and fill the responses with data from fixtures. Everything works just fine, however the tests are insanely slow. Every request takes 5-10 seconds to perform. Which can make a single test with multiple requests sometimes take about 30-40 seconds.

To take a look at this problem I opened the network tab in developer tools and saw that within every single request it is the websocket that takes the full amount of this 5-10 seconds per request. Is there a solution to this or someone has a suggestion how to handle this?

---

I also saw the following article:

https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/05/22/how-we-improved-network-speed-by-300-in-cypress-3-3-0/
They describe having performance issues with network speeds and when using noDelay on the socket, it resolved most of the timing. Is this something I can look into (nodelay on the socket)?